# Git push to heroku

Tags: git, heroku

First, I create new keys using

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "user@mail.com"
```

Then I add the generated key to heroku by `heroku keys:add`.
After that, I tried to push my git repository to heroku using `git push heroku master`.

Before that I have configed my git repository using these commands: `git init`, `git add .`, `git commit`,`heroku create`, `git remote add heroku git@heroku:sth.git`.

However, I got this error `Host key verification failed`.

I'm running ubuntu version 11.10. This is strange.

Comment: What does git remote -v output?

Comment: github git@github.com:crowdvn/CrowdVN.git (fetch)
github git@github.com:crowdvn/CrowdVN.git (push)
heroku git@heroku.com:growing-snow-7014.git (fetch)
heroku git@heroku.com:growing-snow-7014.git (push)

Comment: What does ssh -vvv git@heroku.com output?  This may give more information about where the error is occurring.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is very silly. When it asked whether I wanted to add the host, I just entered without saying yes.

Comment: Just happened to me, too. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think

```
git remote add heroku git@heroku:sth.git
```

should be

```
git remote add heroku git@heroku.com:sth.git
```

i.e. heroku.com rather than just heroku.

Comment: Since I encountered this problem also when I tried to ssh to github, this is not the cause. Btw, I tried and it's the same.